# How do I install hadoop yarn?

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to upload hadoop yarn on pseudo distributed model on a ubuntu 18.04 virtual machine. I'm having the following error:

```
Starting resourcemanager
ERROR: Cannot set priority of resourcemanager process 19723
Starting nodemanagers
localhost: ERROR: Cannot set priority of nodemanager process 19875
pdsh@alex-VirtualBox: localhost: ssh exited with exit code 1
```

> jps

```
18850 DataNode
18691 NameNode
19931 Jps
19103 SecondaryNameNode
```

> java -version

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_252"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_252-8u252-b09-1~18.04-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.252-b09, mixed mode)
```

> hadoop version

```
Hadoop 3.2.1
Source code repository https://gitbox.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r b3cbbb467e22ea829b3808f4b7b01d07e0bf3842
Compiled by rohithsharmaks on 2019-09-10T15:56Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 776eaf9eee9c0ffc370bcbc1888737
This command was run using /opt/hadoop/hadoop-3.2.1/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-3.2.1.jar
```

> cat etc/hadoop/yarn-env.sh

```
#
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

##
## THIS FILE ACTS AS AN OVERRIDE FOR hadoop-env.sh FOR ALL
## WORK DONE BY THE yarn AND RELATED COMMANDS.
##
## Precedence rules:
##
## yarn-env.sh > hadoop-env.sh > hard-coded defaults
##
## YARN_xyz > HADOOP_xyz > hard-coded defaults
##

###
# Resource Manager specific parameters
###

# Specify the max heapsize for the ResourceManager.  If no units are
# given, it will be assumed to be in MB.
# This value will be overridden by an Xmx setting specified in either
# HADOOP_OPTS and/or YARN_RESOURCEMANAGER_OPTS.
# Default is the same as HADOOP_HEAPSIZE_MAX
#export YARN_RESOURCEMANAGER_HEAPSIZE=

# Specify the JVM options to be used when starting the ResourceManager.
# These options will be appended to the options specified as HADOOP_OPTS
# and therefore may override any similar flags set in HADOOP_OPTS
#
# Examples for a Sun/Oracle JDK:
# a) override the appsummary log file:
# export YARN_RESOURCEMANAGER_OPTS="-Dyarn.server.resourcemanager.appsummary.log.file=rm-appsummary.log -Dyarn.server.resourcemanager.appsummary.logger=INFO,RMSUMMARY"
#
# b) Set JMX options
# export YARN_RESOURCEMANAGER_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1026"
#
# c) Set garbage collection logs from hadoop-env.sh
# export YARN_RESOURCE_MANAGER_OPTS="${HADOOP_GC_SETTINGS} -Xloggc:${HADOOP_LOG_DIR}/gc-rm.log-$(date +'%Y%m%d%H%M')"
#
# d) ... or set them directly
# export YARN_RESOURCEMANAGER_OPTS="-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xloggc:${HADOOP_LOG_DIR}/gc-rm.log-$(date +'%Y%m%d%H%M')"
#
#
# export YARN_RESOURCEMANAGER_OPTS=

###
# Node Manager specific parameters
###

# Specify the max heapsize for the NodeManager.  If no units are
# given, it will be assumed to be in MB.
# This value will be overridden by an Xmx setting specified in either
# HADOOP_OPTS and/or YARN_NODEMANAGER_OPTS.
# Default is the same as HADOOP_HEAPSIZE_MAX.
#export YARN_NODEMANAGER_HEAPSIZE=

# Specify the JVM options to be used when starting the NodeManager.
# These options will be appended to the options specified as HADOOP_OPTS
# and therefore may override any similar flags set in HADOOP_OPTS
#
# See ResourceManager for some examples
#
#export YARN_NODEMANAGER_OPTS=

###
# TimeLineServer specific parameters
###

# Specify the max heapsize for the timelineserver.  If no units are
# given, it will be assumed to be in MB.
# This value will be overridden by an Xmx setting specified in either
# HADOOP_OPTS and/or YARN_TIMELINESERVER_OPTS.
# Default is the same as HADOOP_HEAPSIZE_MAX.
#export YARN_TIMELINE_HEAPSIZE=

# Specify the JVM options to be used when starting the TimeLineServer.
# These options will be appended to the options specified as HADOOP_OPTS
# and therefore may override any similar flags set in HADOOP_OPTS
#
# See ResourceManager for some examples
#
#export YARN_TIMELINESERVER_OPTS=

###
# TimeLineReader specific parameters
###

# Specify the JVM options to be used when starting the TimeLineReader.
# These options will be appended to the options specified as HADOOP_OPTS
# and therefore may override any similar flags set in HADOOP_OPTS
#
# See ResourceManager for some examples
#
#export YARN_TIMELINEREADER_OPTS=

###
# Web App Proxy Server specifc parameters
###

# Specify the max heapsize for the web app proxy server.  If no units are
# given, it will be assumed to be in MB.
# This value will be overridden by an Xmx setting specified in either
# HADOOP_OPTS and/or YARN_PROXYSERVER_OPTS.
# Default is the same as HADOOP_HEAPSIZE_MAX.
#export YARN_PROXYSERVER_HEAPSIZE=

# Specify the JVM options to be used when starting the proxy server.
# These options will be appended to the options specified as HADOOP_OPTS
# and therefore may override any similar flags set in HADOOP_OPTS
#
# See ResourceManager for some examples
#
#export YARN_PROXYSERVER_OPTS=

###
# Shared Cache Manager specific parameters
###
# Specify the JVM options to be used when starting the
# shared cache manager server.
# These options will be appended to the options specified as HADOOP_OPTS
# and therefore may override any similar flags set in HADOOP_OPTS
#
# See ResourceManager for some examples
#
#export YARN_SHAREDCACHEMANAGER_OPTS=

###
# Router specific parameters
###

# Specify the JVM options to be used when starting the Router.
# These options will be appended to the options specified as HADOOP_OPTS
# and therefore may override any similar flags set in HADOOP_OPTS
#
# See ResourceManager for some examples
#
#export YARN_ROUTER_OPTS=

###
# Registry DNS specific parameters
###
# For privileged registry DNS, user to run as after dropping privileges
# This will replace the hadoop.id.str Java property in secure mode.
# export YARN_REGISTRYDNS_SECURE_USER=yarn

# Supplemental options for privileged registry DNS
# By default, Hadoop uses jsvc which needs to know to launch a
# server jvm.
# export YARN_REGISTRYDNS_SECURE_EXTRA_OPTS="-jvm server"

###
# YARN Services parameters
###
# Directory containing service examples
# export YARN_SERVICE_EXAMPLES_DIR = $HADOOP_YARN_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/yarn-service-examples
# export YARN_CONTAINER_RUNTIME_DOCKER_RUN_OVERRIDE_DISABLE=true
export YARN_RESOURCEMANAGER_OPTS="--add-modules java.activation"
export YARN_NODEMANAGER_OPTS="--add-modules java.activation"
```

> cat etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License. See accompanying LICENSE file.
-->
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.env-whitelist</name>
        <value>JAVA_HOME,HADOOP_COMMON_HOME,HADOOP_HDFS_HOME,HADOOP_CONF_DIR,CLASSPATH_PREPEND_DISTCACHE,HADOOP_YARN_HOME,HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

The resourcemanager log shows the following:

> cat logs/hadoop-hadoop-resourcemanager-alex-VirtualBox.log

```
sourceManager.java:1535)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to initialize WebAppContext
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.start(HttpServer2.java:1177)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps$Builder.start(WebApps.java:439)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource
  at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.JAXBContextResolver.<init>(JAXBContextResolver.java:41)
  at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.RMWebApp.setup(RMWebApp.java:54)
  while locating org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.JAXBContextResolver

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1025)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
    at com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory$GuiceInstantiatedComponentProvider.getInstance(GuiceComponentProviderFactory.java:345)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ioc.IoCProviderFactory$ManagedSingleton.<init>(IoCProviderFactory.java:202)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ioc.IoCProviderFactory.wrap(IoCProviderFactory.java:123)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ioc.IoCProviderFactory._getComponentProvider(IoCProviderFactory.java:116)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:153)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getComponent(ProviderServices.java:278)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getProviders(ProviderServices.java:151)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.ContextResolverFactory.init(ContextResolverFactory.java:83)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1332)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    at com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.servlet.GuiceContainer.initiate(GuiceContainer.java:121)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:339)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:744)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.init(FilterDefinition.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.initPipeline(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:99)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.init(GuiceFilter.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.initialize(FilterHolder.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:873)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1406)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:427)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.start(HttpServer2.java:1155)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.<clinit>(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:457)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.<init>(RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.java:65)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:133)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.<init>(ModelBuilder.java:156)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.<init>(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:473)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:319)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1170)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:145)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:262)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:249)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:456)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:656)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.json.JSONJAXBContext.<init>(JSONJAXBContext.java:255)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.JAXBContextResolver.<init>(JAXBContextResolver.java:68)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.JAXBContextResolver$$FastClassByGuice$$6a7be7f6.newInstance(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastConstructor.newInstance(FastConstructor.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:105)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataSource
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 83 more
2020-07-24 09:15:25,931 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Transitioning to standby state
2020-07-24 09:15:25,931 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Transitioned to standby state
2020-07-24 09:15:25,932 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Error starting ResourceManager
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebAppException: Error starting http server
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps$Builder.start(WebApps.java:443)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.startWepApp(ResourceManager.java:1231)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.serviceStart(ResourceManager.java:1340)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:194)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.main(ResourceManager.java:1535)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to initialize WebAppContext
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.start(HttpServer2.java:1177)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps$Builder.start(WebApps.java:439)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource
  at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.JAXBContextResolver.<init>(JAXBContextResolver.java:41)
  at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.RMWebApp.setup(RMWebApp.java:54)
  while locating org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.JAXBContextResolver

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1025)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
    at com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory$GuiceInstantiatedComponentProvider.getInstance(GuiceComponentProviderFactory.java:345)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ioc.IoCProviderFactory$ManagedSingleton.<init>(IoCProviderFactory.java:202)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ioc.IoCProviderFactory.wrap(IoCProviderFactory.java:123)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ioc.IoCProviderFactory._getComponentProvider(IoCProviderFactory.java:116)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:153)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getComponent(ProviderServices.java:278)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getProviders(ProviderServices.java:151)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.ContextResolverFactory.init(ContextResolverFactory.java:83)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1332)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    at com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.servlet.GuiceContainer.initiate(GuiceContainer.java:121)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:339)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:744)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.init(FilterDefinition.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.initPipeline(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:99)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.init(GuiceFilter.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.initialize(FilterHolder.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:873)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1406)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:427)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.start(HttpServer2.java:1155)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.<clinit>(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:457)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.<init>(RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.java:65)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:133)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.<init>(ModelBuilder.java:156)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.<init>(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:473)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:319)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1170)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:145)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:262)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:249)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:456)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:656)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.json.JSONJAXBContext.<init>(JSONJAXBContext.java:255)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.JAXBContextResolver.<init>(JAXBContextResolver.java:68)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.JAXBContextResolver$$FastClassByGuice$$6a7be7f6.newInstance(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastConstructor.newInstance(FastConstructor.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:105)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataSource
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 83 more
2020-07-24 09:15:25,997 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down ResourceManager at alex-VirtualBox/127.0.1.1
************************************************************/
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: You need `activation.jar` to be added, for it to work.

Comment: What is the output for `echo $JAVA_HOME`

Comment: @Amit kumar  I downloaded it activation-2.1.3.jar and put it in /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib but the error is same.

Comment: @tashkhisi  the  output  for echo $JAVA_HOME is /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64